# TCPDF's getNumLines() is sometimes wrong

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I use `getNumLines()` to estimate the number of lines before writing the text, besause it has to be positioned accordingly.
It seems that getNumLines() calculates more space for the text then `MultiCell()` actually needs. A long line, that still fits into the cell when writing with `MultiCell()` seems to be soft-wrapped by `getNumLines()`:

```
$lines = $pdf->getNumLines($text, $width);
$pdf->MultiCell($width, 50, $text, 0, "L");
```

In my test `$lines` is 3 while only 2 lines are printed. If I increase the $width a bit I get the right value. And it is the first line that is the longer one. So it can't be a non-printing-character in the end that is wrapped.

Maybe it's because of the align parameter "L" I pass to `MultiCell()`? But there isn't such for `getNumLines()` ... any suggestions?

Version of TCPDF: 5.9.156

Comment: I have the same problem, just that getNumLines() calculates to less space for my string. Any solutions to my problem?

Comment: I'd try the technique described below in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11014007/1060128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! Found the bug: `getNumLines()` calculates space for newlines and carriage returns.

To avoid this I edited the font definition files: There is an array called `$cw` defining the width of each character. I added two entries: `10 => 0, 13 => 0` to set the width of newline and carriage return to zero.

Comment: Found out that this bug ist tracked [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3146697&group_id=128076&atid=710532), [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2972502&group_id=128076&atid=710532) and [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2935534&group_id=128076&atid=710532)

Answer (score 2):

There is another technique described in the comments of [this ticket](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2935534&group_id=128076&atid=710532) of tcpdf's bugtracker, which sounds very promissing:

> If you want o know the exact number of lines you have to use the following
>   technique:

```
// store current object
$pdf->startTransaction();
// get the number of lines
$lines = $pdf->MultiCell($w, 0, $txt, 0, 'L', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false,true, 0);
// restore previous object
$pdf = $pdf->rollbackTransaction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed this same bug for a 'dirty' html-string table in TCPDF.
JohJoh's answer about 10 => 0, 13 => 0 put me in the right direction.
I changed it to 10 => 8750, 13 => 8750 to push the content of other td's down the right amount.