# How can i generate fresh page in tcpdf after the first one and half page

Tags: php, tcpdf

My question is, For example, there are two chapters . The first chapter has one and half page of data in pdf format. When the second chapter starts, it should not start from previous chapters half page, it should get start in next fresh page. These two chapters in while loop. I used the below syntax. Please any one advice me. I am trying since 2 days. Please help me out. I am in starting stage. I am learning tcpdf.

//here is the edited code

```
 while($example = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
 {
        //contains some code


        $sql_chapter    =   mysqli_query($dbconn,"SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM CHAPTER_DETAILS WHERE FORM_NAME='".$example['chapter']."' ");
        while($row_chapter=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_chapter))
        {
           $output  =   $row_chapter['column1']     ;
           $output1 =   fnFetchData($row_chapter['column2'],$row_chapter['column3'])     ;

           $pdf->MultiCell(200, 70, $output, 0, 'L', 0, 0, false);
           $pdf->MultiCell(250, 70, $output1, 0, 'L', 0, 0, false);
        }

        $pdf->AddPage() ;
 }

    $pdf->lastPage();
    $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a new page with AddPage

```
$pdf->AddPage();

// Reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

// Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
```

It should work fine

EDIT

```
while($example = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
 {
    $pdf->startPage() ; // you can also use AddPage();


    $sql_chapter    =   mysqli_query($dbconn,"SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM CHAPTER_DETAILS WHERE FORM_NAME='".$example['chapter']."' ");
    while($row_chapter=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_chapter))
    {
       $output  =   $row_chapter['column1']     ;
       $output1 =   fnFetchData($row_chapter['column2'],$row_chapter['column3'])     ;

       $pdf->MultiCell(200, 70, $output, 0, 'L', 0, 0, false);
       $pdf->MultiCell(250, 70, $output1, 0, 'L', 0, 0, false);
    }
    $pdf->endPage() ; // only if you use startPage();
 }
$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Thank u for your response. But I am not getting the correct answer..i included the code..pls check it out and let me know where i have done mistake..

Comment: You should put your AddPage(); inside the loop otherwise it'll loop first and add a page after that. I'm not sure if thats intended

Comment: do you mean that your details returns an array with 5 values or you need aside details 4 more extra values

Comment: I told that in my database there are 5 columns, and all 5 columns will come in select statement. one column name is  'DETAILS' will be in multicell syntax, and the remaining i am using for some other purpose..                                 I will give you the example sir. There are two output of 2 different files. File  A has one and half page output and file B has one and half page output. When A form executed, the output will be in one and half pdf page(page num 1 and 2) and when i execute B form , the output comes in page num 2...i want the output in page number 3 bcz it is a new form.

Comment: You can do it like this. see edited form after details in multicell it'll set a new page. Than you can add something else like column2,3,4,5 and so on

Comment: try putting your AddPage() function above like this  while($example = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
//contains some code
$pdf->AddPage() ;

Comment: i used foreach loop.. not getting the proper output...In while loop i am getting the proper output...is there any alternative method...if there suggest me

Comment: oke can you edit your code with the database structure of the columns you want and i'll test it for you with the proper code

Comment: i have edited the code..But i din't put the actual database column name..bt the structure is same

Comment: Its coming when the output is more than one page. If the output is only one page, it displaying the next page as blank...

Comment: oke than you have to change startPage to AddPage and delete endPage. How does your $sql look like cuz it brings out empty arrays also. if thats the case you have to put a if statement for the AddPage like if(!empty($example['chapter'])){ $pdf->AddPage(); ....

Comment: Is there any syntax to count the number of lines to a particular pdf page. when the data exceeds the line number it should go to next page. I thought to apply this method. I tried with SetY(). I used $pdf->getNumLines() to get the number of lines. But it dint return any value.

Comment: try this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952848/tcpdfs-getnumlines-is-sometimes-wrong